# Select query using Group By 3 first varchars

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to make a SELECT query which group by 3 first varchars ond shows it onces for each. for example the table "tblanimals":

```
id      name   age
--      ----   ---
1       DOG1   10
2       DOG2   12
3       DOG3   14
4       CAT1   16
5       CAT2   18
```

the output should be:

```
DOG
CAT
```

after it I need to make another (inside loop) simple query to show the details of each result from the last query we made:

```
DOG   DOG1   10
      DOG2   12
      DOG3   14
CAT   CAT1   16
      CAT2   18
```

10X

Comment: BTW can you tell us what actually you wanna accomplish by executing such queries?

Comment: Is this grouping (your last example) required in PHP? Or straight from MySQL? that wont be possible like that

Comment: For this specific example, you should really separate out the string component from the integer component. But either way, this is pretty simple. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query would help you:

**Fiddle** : [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4305/27)

```
select 
(
case i.rank
when 1 then i.subname
else '' end
) groupname,
i.name,i.age
from

 (SELECT SUBSTRING(`NAME`,1,3)AS SUBNAME, t.name,t.AGE ,

       ( 
            CASE SUBSTRING(`NAME`,1,3) 
            WHEN @curType 
            THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1 
            ELSE @rownum := 1 AND @curType := (SUBSTRING(`NAME`,1,3)) END
          )+1 AS rank

  FROM TEST t, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0, @curType := '') r
  ) i
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
GROUPNAME | NAME |  AGE
DOG       | DOG1 |  10
          | DOG2 |  12
          | DOG3 |  14
CAT       | CAT1 |  16
          | CAT2 |  18
```

**QUERY EXPLANATION**

The innerQuery (i) is for Ranking and getting the rownumbers based on the first 3 characters of the animal name. Using case statement to display the animal name only if rownumber=1. A blank character would be displayed if rownumber is anything else other than 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can group this using **[SUBSTR()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substr-function.php)**

```
select SUBSTR(name,1,3) as n from test group by n;
```

## [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2fe13/2)

Result you want:

```
select SUBSTR(name,1,3) as n,id,name,age from test;
```

## [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2fe13/1)

Comment: When grouping is used it's limiting the record set to the first record. They likely meant `order by n` so they could show more than one result.

Comment: I believe that's what op wants @AbsoluteƵERØ

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name,1,3) AS first3Char, name,age FROM test2
GROUP BY first3Char,fName,lName
```

Please check if above Query would serve your purpose.